# VB.net - in WEB context, How can I access variables that are named sequentially by a loop?

Tags: vb.net, variables, loops

im trying to access to the values of some variables that has the following names in  VB.net:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB"%>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>

<%
dim foo1 = "some value1"
dim foo2 = "some value2"
dim foo3 = "some value3"

'DO some stuff

%>
```

In php i can access this type of variables inside a loop like this:

```
$foo1 ="some value1".<br/>
$foo2 ="some value2".<br/>
$foo3 ="some value3".<br/>

for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
   echo ${"foo".$i}
}
```

And this will echo something like this:

```
some value1 
some value2 
some value3
```

How can i do the same in  VB.net?

Basicaly, this what i want to do:

I have a webform written in html and jquery, who uses a VB.net 4 connector (connector.aspx)
thru ajax to receive the data from the form in post and insert the data to the DB.

The form has the  abillity to sign up to 20 participants at once.

The connector has to be prepare to receive up to 400 values, but not all the time it´s gonna receive that.

So, in the code of the connector i uses this tecnic to sweap the Dim´s, to see who has receive a value or who is empty.

Comment: PHP can print to the HTML page. VB.NET has different "displays" depending upon the exact environment you are using: in console-applications, you can write to the console; in form-applications you can put any control (e.g., a label) and write to it; in web-based applications you can do the same than PHP, etc. Do you know this thing of the minimal understanding before asking, don't you?

Comment: ok, soo if i can do the same on php and VB(in web-based aplications), how can i do what i´m asking?

Comment: It seems like you need to get a much better grasp of ASP (btw, next time add the ASP or Silverlight or WebForms tag; VB.NET only is assumed to refer to winforms; the answer you got refers to winforms). You have quite a few alternatives; the most logical one, I guess that is adding a control, like a label (yes, you can also do that in web) and change its text. You might rely on some server-side scripting or even on JavaScript or similar. There are quite a few options and, for all of them (and, in general, to ask here or, at least, to me), you need a minimum knowledge and doing some effort.

Comment: Thanks for the comments men, im new on ASP development. That help me a lot.

Comment: vb.net would be asp.net not asp-classic, though the code you posted is VBScript - which would be asp-classic. Please edit your tags to clarify...

Comment: @eladolo, please, please, please: figure out what language(s) you're using, and tag the question appropriately!!!!!

Comment: @AnonJr: actually, the code he posted is not VBScript - you can't assign a value as part of a dim statement in VBScript. It's some flavor of VB, but he can't seem to be bothered to accurately tell us *what* flavor.

Comment: @Martha - good catch. I was running short on time to a meeting and missed that small detail... and it seems we're still no more clear on what language/framework he's looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "For Each" Loop.  You will need to add your values to a collection first.  Once you have all of your string variables in a collection, your loop will look something like this.

```
For Each tempstring as string in mycollection

    Messagebox.show(tempstring)

Next
```

NOTE: tempstring is a variable that is declared when you create your "For Each" loop.  It represents the current string that you are looping through.  In this example, tempstring would be "some value1" on the first pass, "some value2" on the second etc.

The output in this case would be 3 messageboxes with each of your string values.

Comment: This isn't VBScript - it looks like straight VB, which is related but not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using a Dictionary? Just create a dictionary and place whatever data you need into it. And you can access it by passing in the Key which is the first parameter, this will return the value that was stored with that key.

```
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    dict.Add(1, "some value1")
    dict.Add(2, "some value2")
    dict.Add(3, "some value3")

    For i As Integer = 1 To 3 Step 1
        If dict.ContainsKey(i) Then
            Dim result As String = dict(i)
            'Do whatever with result
            Debug.Print(result)
        End If
    Next
```

1 returns "some value1"

2 returns "some value2"

3 returns "some value3"

Comment: Thanks men, something like that it´s what i do at the end.

Comment: This isn't VBScript. It might be straight VB, which is related but not the same thing.

Comment: Ahh, i see that the post was changed from VB to VBScript

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually are using ASP-classic and VBScript<sup>1</sup>, you can use Eval() to do this.

```
dim foo1, foo2, foo3
dim i, j
foo1 = "blah blah blah"
foo2 = "blibbety"
foo3 = "alohomora"
for i = 1 to 3
    j = "foo" & i
    response.write Eval(j) & "<br>"
next
```

(Adding to a dictionary will also work, but that has much higher overhead.)

<sup>1 The `dim foo = "blah"` syntax you used is not valid in VBScript, and you've been accepting answers that are obviously not written in VBScript either, so I have no idea what language you're actually working in.</sup>

Comment: I try that at the begining but it´s not ASP-classic at all, so Eval() does not work for me, Thanks for the answer any way.

Comment: @eladolo, then why the [expletive deleted] is this question *tagged* "asp-classic"?

Comment: @eladolo, also, Eval() is a part of VBScript, not ASP per se. So if you're actually using VBScript, it should be available. ***What language are you using???????***

Comment: at the beginig I post this like VB.net, cause this the launguage its supouse im using for this development... but AnonJr and varocarbas they complain about it, they told me to change it to VBscript, and honestly i´m feel confuse about it, I´m still think that its asp.net... but this guys who knows much more than me, they complain...sooo that why i change it to VBscript.

Comment: @eladolo: a couple of strangers on the internet cannot possibly know better than you what development environment you're using. They were only going off of what you posted, same as me. Unfortunately, what you've posted has been self-contradictory and unclear. Please, figure out what language you're using, and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do at the end, base on the answers from @Gavin Perkins, @Mike Monge and @varocarbas comments.

```
Dim foo(3)

foo(1) = "some value1"
foo(2) = "some value2"
foo(3) = "some value3"

For i=1 to 3
    Response.Write(foo(i))
next
```

I take the examples from this page:

http://p2p.wrox.com/classic-asp-basics/72328-dynamic-variable-names.html

You need somehow, to put the value and the name(key,etc) on a collection of values 
(array, list, dictionary, etc),
Just like @Gavin_Perkins and @Mike Monge answer, and @varocarbas comment; 
and loop thru the collection, not thru the name of the variable directly.

It can not be done like in the example of php if you are not using ASP-classic and VBScript, like @Martha answered too.